# VBA: Copy specific range from multiple workbooks into one worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a folder with lots (hundreds) of locked `.xls` files.

I need to copy a specific range from one of the worksheets in each file into one big worksheet, which would be my data file for future analysis.

I tried to write a macro for this, but keep getting errors.

Please help me debug what I wrote:

```
Sub ProcessFiles()

    ' declarations & definitions
    Dim Pathname As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim sourceWB As Workbook
    Dim targetWB As Workbook    

    targetWB = ActiveWorkbook
    Pathname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Files\"
    Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xls")        

    ' loop through all files in folder
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Set sourceWB = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename)            

        ' unlock worksheets
        sourceWB.Sheets(4).Visible = True
        sourceWB.Sheets(4).Unprotect Password:="Password"
        sourceWB.Sheets(2).Unprotect Password:="Password"    

        ' create new worksheet
        sourceWB.Sheets.Add After:=8    

        ' copy required cells to new sheets
        sourceWB.Sheets(2).Range("A14:FM663").Copy Destination:=sourceWB.Sheets(9).Range("C2")

        ' fill columns for all rows
        sourceWB.Sheets(9).Range("A2:A663").Value = sourceWB.Name
        sourceWB.Sheets(9).Range("B2:B663").Value = Worksheets(4).Range("C13").Value    

        'move AuxSheet to taget workbook
        sourceWB.Sheets(9).Move Before:=Workbooks(targetWB).Sheets(1)    

        'add to full data worksheet
        targetWB.Sheets(1).Range("A2:FO651").Copy Destination:=sourceWB.Sheets(2).Rows("3:" & Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count)        

        'close file and repeat
        sourceWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop    

    ' save result
    targetWB.Save    

End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheets(4)` and `Sheets(2)` of the opened workbook `sourceWB` ? If the answer is yes, then you need to qualify them by `sourceWB.Sheets(4)` , or adding a `With sourceWB` statement in the begining, anf after use `.Sheets(4)` and `.Sheets(2)`

Comment: You are correct.
 I added the qualifiers but still get :errot 91, object variable not set.

Comment: When you run it in debug mode, at which line?

Comment: Pathname = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Files\"

(I also edited the original question to reflect the edits you suggested)

Comment: You need to Set the object variables: `Set targetWB = ActiveWorkbook`. With object variables, you are only setting a pointer, not actually passing the whole value into the memory.

Comment: **i.** Does `Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Path` return the path you expect? If you run your code from the VBA Editor, chances are that there is still workbook active in your Excel GUI. Maybe u want to use `ThisWorkbook.Path` instead
**ii.** Also, doesn't `sourceWB.Sheets(9).Move Before:=Workbooks(targetWB).Sheets(1)` cause a #13 type-mismatch error? You might be able to just go with `... Before:=targetWB.Sheets(1)`, since `targetWB` is already a `Workbook`-object

Comment: Not sure from where to where you want to copy. One time you have `sourceWB.Sheets(2).Range("A14:FM663").Copy Destination:=sourceWB.Sheets(9).Range("C2")` (copying from `sourceWB` to `sourceWB`). The second you have `targetWB.Sheets(1).Range("A2:FO651").Copy Destination:=sourceWB.Sheets(2).Rows("3:" & Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows.Count)` copying from `targetWB` to `sourceWB`. Is it my logic that you would want to copy from `sourceWB` to `targetWB` ?

Comment: @ShaiRado but looking at the code it's obvious the op adds information in step 1 and then copies it to his `TargetWB` in step 2.

Comment: @MartinDreher when I'm looking at his code I'm confused, I'll let you take this one :)

Comment: @ShaiRado yes, I can relate. ;) Using VBA for what is essentially a database operation gets confusing faster than you'd like

Comment: thanks everyone for the helpful comments!

Comment: @Vacip, Your comment helped me overcome the "object variable not set".

Comment: @MartinDreher, ThisWorkbook is much better in this context.
Didn't get type msimatch errors.
did get subscript out of range error on: 
`sourceWB.Sheets(9).Range("B2:B663").Value = Worksheets(4).Range("C13").Value`
because C13 is part of several merged cells

Comment: @ShaiRado, Yes, I got one refrence wrong, but let me exlain the logic:
First, I copy the range in need to another shhet inside the same workbook, and copy some source refernce from the same workbook.
Second, I move the whole worksheet into the target workbook, and close the source workbook.
Last I copy the range I need from the copied worksheet and paste it at the end of the target data worksheet.
It's not very elegant, I know. I still need to correct the last lines.

Comment: @BoazTzur do you need the copying of the sheets ? or you just started implementing it this way ? You could just copy the needed range from `sourceWB` directly to `targetWB` to the next empty row

Comment: @ShaiRado, No, I intend to delete the sheets eventually. 
It was just easier for me - because I want to add two columns with data about the source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give you an idea of how tasks like this can be handled way more efficient... consider the following that I always use for tasks like this:

```
Option Explicit

' 1. Add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime and Access Data Objects Library via Extras>References
Sub ProcessFiles()



    Dim strCon As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim myfile As file

    With ThisWorkbook

        ' 2. empty your outputsheet
        .Sheets("out").Cells.Clear

        ' 3. loop the files in your folder
        For Each myfile In fso.GetFolder(.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Files").Files

            ' 3.1. no proper way to filter files like in Dir(), but we want to use the file objects
            If myfile.Name Like "*.xls" Then

                ' 3.1.1. Construct the connection string, the only variable part is myfile.Path
                strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & myfile.Path & ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES';"
                ' 3.1.2. Construct the SQL String. Luckily, you already know where your data is
                strSQL = "SELECT '" & myfile.Name & "' AS WorkbookName, * FROM [sheetData$A1:C5], (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [sheetSchool$C12:C13])"

                ' 3.1.3. Call the get-data sub from below
                GetData .Sheets("out"), strCon, strSQL

            End If

        Next myfile

    End With

End Sub

Sub GetData(ByRef wsOut As Variant, strCon As String, strSQL As String)

    Dim i As Integer

    On Error GoTo skpError
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Create a new database connection
    Dim objCon As New ADODB.Connection
    With objCon
        .ConnectionString = strCon
        .Open
    End With

    ' Create a new database command
    Dim objCmd As New ADODB.Command
    With objCmd
        .ActiveConnection = objCon
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        .CommandText = strSQL
        Debug.Print .CommandText
    End With

    ' Create a new recordset
    Dim objRS
    Set objRS = New ADODB.Recordset
    With objRS
        .ActiveConnection = objCon
        .Open objCmd
    End With

    ' Print your FieldNames, in case they're not already there
    With wsOut
        If wsOut.Cells(1, 1).Value = vbNullString Then
            For i = 1 To objRS.Fields.Count
                .Cells(1, i).Value = _
                    objRS.Fields(i - 1).Name
            Next i
        End If

        ' Output your data - pretty ugly, but reliable
        .Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset (objRS)

    End With

skpNoError:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

skpError:
    MsgBox "Error #" & Err & vbNewLine & Error, vbCritical
    GoTo skpNoError
End Sub
```

**Notes: (why use something like this?)**

- protected and hidden worksheets shouldn't be a problem with this. For protected workbooks, a password parameter can be added to the connection string
- this will be considerably faster for a large number of files than opening, editing, copying would be. If you feel fancy, you can further speed things up by moving stuff from the `GetData`-Sub to `ProcessFiles`, so they won't get called repeatedly.
- you use a database language for querying data instead of some clumsy copy/paste mechanism.

**Edit:** 
Edited my code, for me this works with the example you gave.

- From what i gather, you only got protected `Worksheets`, not a password-protected `Workbook` - therefore there's no need to unhide or unprotect your worksheets
- adjust the line `strSQL = "SELECT '" & myfile.Name & "' AS WorkbookName, * FROM [sheetData$A1:C5], (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [sheetSchool$C12:C13])"` to contain your actual `Sheets(2)` and `Sheets(4)` names

Comment: Thank you @MartinDreher ! This looks very helpful. I will see how I can apply this to my exact needs.    Regaring the merged cells - I am aware that this complicates things, but the source files were not written by me. (The cells coaintain the name of the data source, which is not found in the filename)

Comment: Ok. You can retrieve the `.Value` of a merged cell with SQL. Add a screenshot of the `Worksheets(4).Range("C13").Value` with the surrounding cells

Comment: k. You can retrieve the .Value of a merged cell with SQL. Add a screenshot of the `Worksheets(4).Range("C13").Value` with the surrounding cells, so we can determine the SQL needed. In my example, `strSQL = "SELECT '" & myfile.Name & "' AS WorkbookName, * FROM [Tabelle1$A1:C5], (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Tabelle2$C12:C13])"` works like a charm and retrieves what you want. My example took about 20sec for 300 files

Comment: Thanks! Here is a screenshot of the cell and immediate area http://imgur.com/YvC3oLa.  also, how do I add a password unprotection to the connection string?

Comment: Thanks again for your help!